# React - Axios promise pending value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios, autosuggest

I'm trying to build a weather app using React, react-autosuggest for a dropdown listing available cities and for api fetching Axios.

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CityWeather from './components/CityWeather';
import SearchWeather from './components/SearchWeather';




class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestedCities: [],
            cityWeatherData: [],
            currentWeather: [],
        }
    };

    handleCityWeatherData = (city) => {
        this.setState({
            cityWeatherData: city
        });
    };

    handleOnChange = (newValue) => {
        this.setState({
            value: newValue
        });
    }

    render() {

        // Finally, render it!
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchWeather suggestData={{value: this.state.value, suggestedCities: this.state.suggestedCities}} onSelectCity={this.handleCityWeatherData} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                <CityWeather weatherData={this.state.cityWeatherData}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Apis.jsx

```
import Axios from "axios";

//local file
let cities = "./public/cities.json";


export default {
    getCities: function(){
        return  Axios.get(cities).then((res) => {
            console.log("from apis", res.data.cities);
            resolve(res.data.cities);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("from apis.jsx", error);
            []
        });
    },
    getTest: function(){
        return 'hello';
    }
    //add api for weather
};
```

I'm having trouble getting the data, so in `SearchWeather.jsx` I would like to fetch the list of cities by using a function, `const cities = apis.getCities()` where it retrieves the data from a different file, `Apis.jsx` where Axios is being utilized under `getCities` method.  The error occurs in `api.getCities`, in the console it says `<promise> pending` and I get an undefined to the `cities` variable.  Not sure how to go about this, I tried to add `await` before `getCities` in `api.jsx` but didn't do anything.  I can use `fetch` instead of `Axios` but I would like use `Axios` and learn more about.  I'm sure it's got to do in the `const cities = apis.getCities()`, but not sure how to go about it, I think I need to use resolve but don't know how.  New to react, so I'm sure I'm missing something.  Your help will be appreciated!

SearchWeather.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import apis from '../utils/apis';


const getSuggestions = (value) => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;


    const cities = apis.getCities().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data;
    });

    console.log('calling from getSuggestions');
    console.log(cities); //this is undefined from const cities


    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : cities.filter(city =>

        city.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
    );
};

// When suggestion is clicked, Autosuggest needs to populate the input
// based on the clicked suggestion. Teach Autosuggest how to calculate the
// input value for every given suggestion.
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name;

// Use your imagination to render suggestions.
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
  <span>{suggestion.name}</span>
);

class SearchWeather extends Component {

    onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
        this.props.onChange(newValue);
    };

    // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to update suggestions.
    // You already implemented this logic above, so just use it.
    onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
        this.setState({
          suggestedCities: getSuggestions(value)
        });
    };

    // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
    onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
        this.setState({
          suggestedCities: []
        });
    };

    renderSuggestionsContainer = ({ containerProps, children, query }) => {
        return (
            <div {...containerProps}>
                {children}
                <h5>I like showing up.</h5>
            </div>
        );
    };

    fetchCityWeather = (cityId) => {
        //fetching sample request
        Axios.get("/public/sampleWeather.json").then((response) => {
            if(response.status === 200){
                return response.data
            }
            else{
                console.log('fetchCityWeather - something went wrong');
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

    onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion, suggestionValue, suggestionIndex, sectionIndex, method }) => {
        console.log(suggestion);
        console.log(method);

        if(method == 'click'){
            let cityId = suggestion.id;
            let data = this.fetchCityWeather(cityId);
            this.props.onSelectCity(data); //pass data to parent
        }
    };


    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
    }


    render(){
        const value = this.props.suggestData.value;
        const suggestedCities = this.props.suggestData.suggestedCities;

        // Autosuggest InputProps
        const inputProps = {
          placeholder: 'Type your city',
          value,
          onChange: this.onChange
        };

        return(
            <Autosuggest
                suggestions={suggestedCities}
                onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
                getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
                renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
                inputProps={inputProps} 
                shouldRenderSuggestions = {(v) => v.trim().length > 0}
                renderSuggestionsContainer={this.renderSuggestionsContainer}
                onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default SearchWeather;
```

Note:  I put the api calls in a different file just for organizing purposes and would like to keep it that way unless it's not the right way to do it.

Additional Info:

I changed `const cities` to this:

```
const cities = apis.getCities().then((data) => {
        console.log("from getCities", data);
        return data;
    });
```

and I noticed in the console the following in order:

from `console.log(cities)` in `SearchWeather`

`Promise {<pending>}`

from `Apis.jsx` `console.log("from apis", res.data.cities);`, the data

`from apis (4) [{..},{..}]`

from `SearchWeather`, `console.log("from getCities", data);`

`from getCities (4) [{..},{..}]`

Don't know if this helps but `const cities` is being skipped then comes back and it prints the actual data

Answer (score 1):

Axios cannot request to URL like `let cities = "./public/cities.json";`

If you put this json file on public folder you can set URL like

`http://localhost:3001/public/cities.json`

don't forgot port. This is HTTP request to host, not just read local file.

Comment: That sounds more like it 

Comment: @SungKim I have a similar mistake when begin with React.js so I think this way can solve

Comment: Axios is able to read it since the file lives in the build folder

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I noticed is this:

`let cities = "./public/cities.json";`

In order to read the file into your code, you have to use require, like this:

`let cities = require('./public/cities.json');`

or as in ES6

`import cities from './public/cities.json'`

whatever rests you well.

Second thing I noticed is that you're returning Axios after the first promise is resolved (in which you aren't returning anything at all). You could either go like this:

```
getCities: function(){
   return  Axios.get(cities)
},
```

or this:

```
    getCities: function(){
        return  Axios.get(cities).then(res => res.data.cities).catch(...) // return cities
    },
```

Why is this?

Because after wrapping it up with a `.then` function, you're resolving it, and whatever its returned inside this then, becomes another promise, allowing you to chain it with another then, or in your case, this:

```
apis.getCities().then((data) => {
    const cities = data
});
```

If using the first one I wrote, you'll get the response back in the data argument in this function. The second one will get you the cities right straight into data.

Edit:

Since I misread the code and my answer didn't make any sense, I'm editing my answer:

In order to get the response from the async promise, you have to pass a callback (or go async/await) to your function, like this:

Apis.jsx

```
/**/
    getCities : cb => Axios.get(cities).then(res => cb(res.data.cities))
/**/
```

SearchWeather.jsx

```
const getSuggestions = (value, cb) => {
/**/
    apis.getCities().then(cities => {
       /* your logic to filter cities goes here */

       // return your filtered cities here 
       return cb(filteredCities)
    });
}

class SearchWeather extends Component{
/**/
    onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
        const cb = suggestedCities => this.setState({ suggestedCities })

        return getSuggestions(value, cb)
    };
/**/
}
```

`cb` (or callback) will be triggered after resolving the promise.

Comment: Axios is able to read file without the `require`, the file exists in the build folder.  I tried the first way but still getting the promise pending.  What should be the `const cities` then?  `const cities = apis.getCities();`? if doing the second way, also what's `cb` in the function?

Comment: I'm fixing my answer since I misread your code. Actually, that cb at first was supposed to be a callback because in order to retrieve the result of a promise (without going async/await), is with a callback.